# extract time from now() in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract the time part only (excluding milliseconds) from the date-time string in amazon redshift.

I used:

```
Select now()::time;
```

But it is giving me error.

`Error running query: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Redshift seems to support only `date` and `timestamp`, you probably need to return it as a string.

Comment: Select now()::time; worked fine for me on redshift and returned "09:12:21" which is UTC time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm less sure about the error, but I agree with Jon Scott's comment, the following query runs fine without any error.

```
Select now()::time;
```

It outputs something like:

> 09:23:49.697401

It contains time with 6 digits after seconds.

If you just add time parameter up to, how many digits your need after seconds like below. Here its `0`.

```
Select now()::time(0);
```

This will output:

> 09:23:49

If you do;

```
Select now()::time(1);
```

This will output:

> 09:23:49.6

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: This worked for me interactively in psql, but I get the OP's error above when running a script with psql.

Answer (score 1):

Use below select clause returning the exact required result for time

```
Select CURRENT_TIME::time(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find `now()` in RedShift documentation although selecting now() works. Instead, RedShift offers
`select getdate()` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html)) which gives you the recent date.

Comment: Now() is defined as deprecated in the Redshift docs - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html  (bottom of page).  Now() is defined to give the exact time of the system clock at the point in time that the function is run and Redshift being a cluster doesn't have only one system clock. So this is defined as a leader-node only function which is not helpful in querying.  Other more useful functions - getdate() returns the time that the SQL statement begins and sysdate() returns the time that the current transaction started.  Both usable in queries.